# Repository-UoW, EF POCO, RIA Services, ASP MVC & Silverlight cooperation possible?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, repository, wcf-ria-services

I 'm beginning a new web project and was wondering if i could benefit from the "magical" things RIA service can offer, but in a way i was used to develop until now.

This means i would like to architect the solution so that EF POCOs should be used, which are the basis for repositories (using IoC to resolve to concrete implementations), which the RIA service(s) use to be consumed by ASP MVC or Silverlight UI.

What concerns me a lot: will the Silverlight UI  have all the MVVM-infrastructure (change notification,...)?

Is this feasible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/30/silverlight-4-mvvm-with-commanding-and-wcf-ria-services.aspx) has a lot of what i 'm willing to do.